# How to use Go language with NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, ide, editor, go

How to setup Go language in NetBeans IDE?. 
(Like i am already using Python, C/C++, Java, Php, BASH already in one NetBeans IDE).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I've never used it, there appears to only be one [Go plugin for NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/25606/go). Their [official website](http://www.winsoft.sk/go.htm) says that it provides syntax highlighting and templates for Go. I'm not sure if it's everything you're looking for, but it appears to be the only option at this point in time.

Comment: It's useful enough, if all you're looking for is syntax highlighting, and a major step forward for Netbeans. But it doesn't seem to support a Go project type yet. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I can confirm that, there seems to be no support for projects, yet. For now it will do by opening just files.

Comment: Plugin not available anymore. Could not find because of changes of the site. But hints of Igor Maznitsa are working

Answer (score 2):

because NetBeans is maven-oriented IDE just out of the box, I use NB with maven through [mvn-golang plugin](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang) and [made some very restricted plugin contains project and file templates](https://github.com/raydac/nb-mvn-golang-plugin), may be in future will make syntax highlighting